# What movies does this ad for the Action Movie Kid book reference?

Tags: story-identification, movie, action-movie-kid

[*Action Movie Kid*](https://www.youtube.com/c/theActionMovieKid/about) is a Youtube channel of visual effects artist Daniel Hashimoto aka Action Movie Dad, where he publishes short video skits of his two superhero children, James and Sophia.  In 2015, the author also published a book, also titled *Action Movie Kid*, based on the superhero adventures of James.

My question is about [a video advertisment for this book, titled “AMK Vlog: Most Important Book of All TIME?!?”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjvK9vEYnsQ).  The first half of this video shows scenes from classic movies, where a book that is shown in the movie is replaced by the *Action Movie Kid* book, regardless of whether that makes sense in the context of the movie.  I would like to know what those movies are.

1. The first scene is from the *Neverending story* movie, when Bastian first sees the book in the used book shop.  He asks about the book, the shop owner starts to answer but is then called away by the telephone ringing.
2. Second is a scene from *The Princess Bride*, where the grandpa first introduces the book to his ill grandson.
3. I do not recognize the third scene.  A gentleman in a suit and tie, between a bookshelf of lexicons and a bronze bust, shows a thick book to another person, saying “Now, not everything in this book of course applies to you, but I'm sure that you can see, when you see the title, exactly how it could help.”  A web search for that line of dialog didn't lead me to an obvious answer.

   [image: (screencap from the video showing the gentleman as he shows the book)]

   [image: (screencap showing the other man)]
4. I also don't recognize the fourth scene.  A man is holding a large book close to his shoulder, and a woman asks “What's in that book? Let me see it.”  The woman tries to reach for the book, but the man doesn't give it to her.

   [image: (screencap)]
5. The fifth scene is from *Back to the Future*, when Biff receives the *Gray's Sports Almanac*.
6. I don't recognize the sixth scene either.  In this, two men are standing next to a drawing featured in an art gallery, and one explains “It's a classic depiction of good versus evil.  This is an art gallery, my friend, and this is a piece of art.”  The other replies something like “Now my kids are going to go berserk.”

   [image: (screencap of closeup on the two character's heads)]
7. There's a final short scene where a child with glasses looks at a handwritten note in what appears to be a toilet cubicle, and says “A crummy commercial?”

   [image: (screencap of child)]

(Meta note: *Action Movie Kid* is a fantasy book, so I think this ad is on topic regardless of whether the movies that it references are on topic or not.)

Comment: Hmm. I'm on the borderline of voting to close this. Some of the Movie-IDs are sci-fi/fantasy-related, but the bulk aren't. I'll leave it since I've answered it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scene (#3) containing Richard Dreyfuss and Bill Murray is from the film *[What About Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_About_Bob%3F)?*

[image]

The scene (#4) with Sir Anthony Hopkins and Dame Emma Thompson is from *[The Remains of the Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Remains_of_the_Day_(film))*

[image]

You may want to note that the scene (#5) with Thomas F. Wilson is from [*Back to the Future Part II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_II), not [*Back to the Future*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future).

[image]

The scene (#6) where Samuel L. Jackson is speaking to Firdous Bamji is from the film *[Unbreakable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbreakable_(film))*.

[image]

The final scene (#7) with Peter Billingsley is from *[A Christmas Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Story)*

[image]

Comment: Indeed, https://youtu.be/lqTy3Bc8m_s?t=77 shows the scene in the movie “What About Bob?”.

Comment: The relevant scene from *A Christmas Story* is https://youtu.be/zdA__2tKoIU .